# Creating a "Notification Bubble" in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have been working on this for a while now and cannot seem to figure it out. I have a home page in Microsoft Access with numerous embed subforms. One of these subforms is a recent activity feed similar to what you might see on most social media platforms. It is a tabbed subfrom with a "Recent Events" and a "Notes" section. I am trying to have a "Notification Bubble" appear when an item in that subform has been added in the last 24 hours, and THEN disappear when the user clicks on the corresponding tab.

The "Notification Bubble" is a picture called "recentalert". Currently, the bubble only appears when the 24 hour criteria is met but I cannot get it to disappear once the corresponding tab is clicked. I have tried numerous formats and different events with no luck. My code is below. Please help!

```
    Private Sub Recent_Click()
        If Me.recentalert.Visible = True Then
            Me.recentalert.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load
        If [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSub]![Activity Feed]![RAevents_frm].[Form].[today_date] >= Date -1 Then
            Me.recentalert.visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `.visible` maybe?

Comment: Since you got the bubble to appear with `Me.recentalert.visible = True`, have you tried `Me.recentalert.visible = False` to hide it?

Comment: My OnClick event above should make the picture invisible if visible = true but it is not working for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure that your `Recent_Click()` code is firing? You could add a notification like `MsgBox "Firing"` into the sub to check this.

Comment: You have no handling for `.visible=false` once it's dissapeared.  Try just `Me.recentalert.Visible = not Me.recentalert.Visible`

Comment: .visible=false doesn't unload the control, you don't need a special handler for it. Plus this code will make the picture visible again after clicking on the tab, which is not what he is asking for.

Comment: Nathan, Jeffery is correct the `= not.me` control just toggles visibility. Once I click the button I want the image to disappear unless the form is reloaded and a new event meets the 24 hour criteria. @user3728595 you might be on to something, after checking to see if the `Recent_Click()` event worked with an error message nothing happened. Any idea why my `OnClick` is not firing?

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the control where you want the On Click event to fire and click on Build Event. This should take you to the Recent_Click sub in your module, if not, your control isn't properly linked and I would suggest deleting the sub in your module, using the right click method above, click on Code Builder, then retyping in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry this was a retype error on my part. My code is recentalert.visible. I also noticed I typed a curly bracket in the code above on accident. It is a square bracket in my code.

Comment: In your form design screen, on the Event tab of the Recent control, make sure your On Click event says [Event Procedure]

Comment: Is the Picture and the tab on the same form or is one in a subform and the other on the main form or another subform?

Comment: The On Click event says [Event Procedure]. The "Activity Feed" is a tabbed subform embedded on the main "Navigation Form" homepage. The "recentalert" picture is on the "Recent" tab of the "Activity Feed" subform. On the "Recent" tab there is another continous subform "RAevents_frm" where the "today_date" field is located. If any of that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Are you using Option Explicit? If not add it to the top of every form module you have and run Debug > Compile. I'm not seeing why this won't work, so short of you having something spelled incorrectly, I'm at a loss.

Comment: I was not, however, I just added it and complied with no errors. After what a user said above it seems my problem is that the OnClick Event is not firing for some reason.

Comment: I changed my answer above, see if that helps.

Comment: That is what I did originally to build the event which leads me to believe that "Recent" is the appropriate control. I don't know if there is something in access where a tab on tabbed form can't also by a cmd button, but I tried an OnClick with a different button with no luck.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working, I just created a tab control on a form, inserted that form into another form, opened the main form and clicked on the tab and it ran the code just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I'll try a few new things and post back if I figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think (based on my tests in Access 2013) that the `Recent` control refers to the page which is revealed, not the tab itself. If the tab control which contains this page is called `TabControl1` try putting your code into the procedure `TabControl1_Change()`.

Comment: I just figured out the tabindex numbers myself so I do believe you are correct. I need to do an OnChange and reference the tabindex=0 instead of "Recent". I am dealing with some database corruption issues now so I have to put this on hold but that should be promising.